# Is there a way to set defaults for package.xml (Maintainer name

Tags: ros, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm hoping to set it so that when I catkin_create_pkg the package.xml will be populated with my name as the maintainer and my email address as the maintainer email. It'd also be a bonus to have GPLV3 set as the license.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204444/is-there-a-way-to-set-defaults-for-package.xml-(maintainer-name/) by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is. See the output of catkin_create_pkg --help

```
catkin_create_pkg --help
usage: catkin_create_pkg [-h] [-s [SYS_DEPS [SYS_DEPS ...]]]
                         [-b [BOOST_COMPS [BOOST_COMPS ...]]] [-V PKG_VERSION]
                         [-D DESCRIPTION] [-l LICENSE] [-a AUTHOR]
                         [-m MAINTAINER] [--rosdistro ROSDISTRO]
                         name [dependencies [dependencies ...]]

Creates a new catkin package

positional arguments:
  name                  The name for the package
  dependencies          Catkin package Dependencies

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s [SYS_DEPS [SYS_DEPS ...]], --sys-deps [SYS_DEPS [SYS_DEPS ...]]
                        System Dependencies
  -b [BOOST_COMPS [BOOST_COMPS ...]], --boost-comps [BOOST_COMPS [BOOST_COMPS ...]]
                        Boost Components
  -V PKG_VERSION, --pkg_version PKG_VERSION
                        Initial Package version
  -D DESCRIPTION, --description DESCRIPTION
                        Description
  -l LICENSE, --license LICENSE
                        Name for License, (e.g. BSD, MIT, GPLv3...)
  -a AUTHOR, --author AUTHOR
                        A single author, may be used multiple times
  -m MAINTAINER, --maintainer MAINTAINER
                        A single maintainer, may be used multiple times
  --rosdistro ROSDISTRO
                        The ROS distro (default: environment variable
                        ROS_DISTRO if defined)
```

If you want to "permanently" fix some of these settings for your on your machine it's probably the easiest way to add a bash alias to your ~/.bashrc file as @ahendrix suggested in his comment:

```
alias my_create_pkg catkin_create_pkg -l GPLv3 -a nobody@nowhere.com
```

Then call it anywhere like

```
my_create_pkg my_new_package_name roscpp other_depending_package
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-07**:
I think @Benjamin Blumer is asking for a way to configure this once, so that it will be used in all future invocations of `catkin_create_pkg`. The command line options you showed do allow users to specify values to be set, but this will have to be repeated each invocation of `catkin_create_pkg`.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-03-07**:
Even if this can't be set in a config file, it should be possible to create a bash alias which passes the desired arguments, something like `alias my_create_pkg catkin_create_pkg -l GPLv3 -a nobody@nowhere.com`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-09**:
<del>@Wolf: I think you'll need to append `$*` to that.</del> Not for an alias, obviously.

**Comment by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on 2015-03-10**:
Yeah, I was hoping for a ROS config file to edit. In the absence of such a file, I'll settle for making an alias.

**Comment by [AlexChris003](https://answers.ros.org/users/33847/alexchris003/) on 2018-02-23**:
Has something happend in this time to this topic? Just want to put the maintainer information in, but the command only takes my name, not my email address.

**Comment by [huangzonghao](https://answers.ros.org/users/36659/huangzonghao/) on 2019-04-27**:
Same here, still looking for a decent way to set default values once for all. Hopefully something like git global configuration file would emerge.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-28**:
@AlexChris003 and @huangzonghao: the fastest way to get this implemented would be to contribute a PR yourself. Waiting for others to do this will probably not result in things moving quickly.

**Comment by [huangzonghao](https://answers.ros.org/users/36659/huangzonghao/) on 2019-04-28**:
@gvdhoorn Yep, everyone knows that.

**Comment by [rkent](https://answers.ros.org/users/55154/rkent/) on 2021-11-16**:
I came across this question looking for why ros2 pkg create set a default name for me. Looked at the code, it uses (from python) getpass.getuser(). That module says:

```
This function checks the environment variables LOGNAME, USER, LNAME and USERNAME, in order, and returns the value of the first one which is set to a non-empty string. If none are set, the login name from the password database is returned on systems which support the pwd module, otherwise, an exception is raised.
```

I tried this by exporting LOGNAME and it seems to work.